# How can I ignore a lint error for a line with Sublime Text 3 Anaconda?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter, sublime-anaconda

I'm using [Anaconda](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda) with Sublime text 3. I have left the lint settings as default with the exception of the following overrides which I've included in a .sublime-project file.

```
"settings": {
        "anaconda_gutter_marks": true,
        "anaconda_gutter_theme": "alpha",
        "anaconda_linting_behaviour": "always",

    }
```

I'd like to be able to ignore "line too long" for certain lines, specifically ones with [urls in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10740010/27604). I like having it for other lines so I would rather not disable it entirely.

I've only found information on doing this for pylint but I'd rather use the default linter if that is possible since that seems to come with its [own issues](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda#using-pylint-as-pyflakes-and-pep8-alternatives) in this plugin.

I've included the sublimelinter tag because anaconda states it's linting is based off of that plugin.

Comment: Daniel Rucci, please, accept Nostalg.io answer, if it works for you. At 2018 Anaconda support `#noqa`. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of today (Oct 15, 2017), it appears to me that you ***can*** use the `# noqa` syntax with Anaconda for Sublime Text 3. For line too long, you would add `# noqa E501` to the end of the line.

Example:

```python
shipping_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='order_shipping_set') # noqa E501
```

Comment: I assumed by putting `E501` at the end, it would *only* ignore "line too long" errors.  But it seems to ignore all lint errors.  (I have a line that's 200 characters, and I added `# noqa E231` expecting to see the `E501` error show ...it did not though).  Is that correct, or am I perhaps doing something wrong?

Answer (score 79):

To disable lints for specific errors, go to the Anaconda.sublime-settings file (Preferences > Packages Settings > Anaconda > Settings).  There you will find several options depending on which linter you are using.

For example, to disable linting for "line too long" for pep8, fill in the following:

```
"pep8_ignore":
[
    "E501"
],
```

Also, the easiest way to find out the correct error code is to the view the lint error itself at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: This question asks how to ignore errors _on certain lines only_, which your answer does not address.

Comment: First time you're changing Anaconda user settings? Go to `Preferences > Packages Settings > Anaconda > Settings - User` then verbatim use `{ "pep8_ignore": ["E501"] }` in order to get valid JSON.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom yes but incase anyone else is looking for the ignore all case this is the answer. still useful information and on topic

Answer (score 11):

I am afraid that you can't ignore an error type (like line too long) just for some lines. You can't disable just warnings or violations neither.

It would be possible to implement some custom system like the `#noqa` comment in `flake8` to make the plugin able to just ignore certain lines of code but this has to be implemented as it's not supported by the plugin and there are no plans to use `flake8` in replacement of `PyFlakes` and `pep8` that are already being used by separate.

There is a similar (but in a much more abstract way) request already in the issues in the GitHub project, you can find it here https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues/142

Comment: Update: @DamnWidget closed the above-mentioned issue a couple of weeks after posting this.
Now using  `# noqa error_number` with certain numbers (E501 included) will work. See the above link (in this answer) for the full list of error numbers that it will work with.
Figured an update would save some people some clicks.

Comment: How would I disable all warning and violations? I would like only errors to be displayed.

Comment: Currently is not possible to ignore certain error types, you can always open a new issue in our Github project page and me or any other contributor can study its convenience.

Comment: One way to do achieve this today, is to set {"anaconda_linting": false} and use SublimeLinter-flake8 in combination with `# flake8: noqa`

Comment: I think @CraigFischer has the best answer for this issue (out of many similar topics)

Answer (score 2):

- Go to the Anaconda.sublime-settings file,

  **Preferences > Packages Settings > Anaconda > Settings**
- There you will find several options depending on which linter you are using.

  For example, to disable linting for "line too long" for pep8, fill in the following:

  ```
  "pep8_ignore":
      [
      "E501"
      ],
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings - User

```
{
    "pep8_max_line_length": 120
}
```

Comment: a better choice than ignore - set to `100` for `pylint`