# How to break long string lines for PEP8 compliance?

Tags: python, string, pep8

I have many long lines like this in the project and don't know how to break it to keep PEP8 happy.
PEP8 shows warning from `.format(me['id'])`

```
pic_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?width=100&height=100".format(me['id'])
```

How can I break the line to get rid of PEP8 warning and yet don't break the code?

Comment: Related: [How should I format a long url in a python comment and still be PEP8 compliant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10740010/1014938)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

```
pic_url = ("http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/"
           "picture?width=100&height=100".format(me['id']))
```

Comment: I don't know, as sourced in the comments, I don't thinking breaking a url into two lines is worth the PEP compliance. It makes both reading and editing it harder to do in the future. I think it's better to just let the line be too long.

Comment: @JaredGoguen, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds