# PEP8 breaking long string in assert

Tags: python

I have this line of code:

```
assert 0 <= j <= self.n, "First edge needs to be between 0 and {}".format(self.n)
```

I want pep8 to be happy, but I don't understand how to break this line. I tried breaking after the comma and got invalid syntax. I've tried breaking the string with additional ""'s as in [How to break long string lines for PEP8 compliance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949525/how-to-break-long-string-lines-for-pep8-compliance). PEP8 was happy but the assert only produced the first half of the message.

What is the proper way to break long assert strings?

Comment: Break PEP8 instead.

Comment: You could add a backslash after the comma and put the rest on a new line.

Comment: Personally, I'd go for a *slightly* more readable version: Assign the failure message to a variable, and use that variable in assert.

Comment: See also [How can I break up this long line in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058925/how-can-i-break-up-this-long-line-in-python)

Comment: You might not need to break your lines anymore, and even if, fstring works better for these kinds of use cases:  ```assert 0 <= j <= self.n, f"First edge needs to be between 0 and {self.n}"``` It is more concise.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use parens:

```
assert 0 <= j <= self.n, ("First edge needs to be "
                          "between 0 and {}".format(self.n))
```

Or:

```
assert 0 <= j <= self.n, ("First edge needs to be between 0 and {}"
                          .format(self.n))
```

Or use the parens of the `format` function:

```
assert 0 <= j <= self.n, "First edge needs to be between 0 and {}".format(
    self.n)
```

Answer (score 8):

Considering [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) statements can be optimized away when you run the interpreter with the `-O` option, you probably want to keep it a single statement and use string concatenation in parenthesis:

```
assert 0 <= j <= self.n, ('First edge needs to be between '
                          '0 and {}'.format(self.n))
```

or using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) in Python 3.6+:

```
assert 0 <= j <= self.n, ('First edge needs to be between '
                          f'0 and {self.n}')
```

If you don't care about optimization (e.g. you're writing tests), then breaking the line into two statements is also an option:

```
message = 'First edge needs to be between 0 and {}'.format(self.n)
assert 0 <= j <= self.n, message
```

Answer (score 3):

You can force breaking to a new line like this:

```
assert 0 <= j <= self.n,\
       "print stuff"
```

That always makes the line continue, if brackets and such aren't doing it automatically.  And you can indent the next line to wherever makes it the most readable, as I did above.