# Exclude comments from Sphinx literalinclude

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I tried to document my main program using sphinx. I couldn't figure out how to use the `autodoc` functionalities to utilize the functionality of `literalinclude` including `start-after` and `end-before`. Does someone know how to do this using autodoc? I was only able to use it do document a class or a class module.

**Main.py [to be documented]**

```
#Label_BasicLibraries_Start
IGNORE: 
This libraries are imported basic libraries.
IGNORE:
import time
import json
import urllib.parse
import random

from functools import reduce
import os.path
#Label_BasicLibraries_End
```

This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
Title Example
=======================================================
This is beautiful code.

.. literalinclude:: Main.py
  :language: python
  :start-after: #Label_BasicLibraries_Start
  :end-before: #Label_BasicLibraries_End
  :linenos:
```

I am able to filter the total program using both alternatives. Is there a way to exclude specific lines starting with a fixed marker or in between other markers? Like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534184/can-sphinx-ignore-certain-tags-in-python-docstrings) for docstrings?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @mzjn Yeah I tried to introduce that solution, but I can not use autodoc.between. I am only able to use ```literalinclude```.

Comment: I couldn't find something likewise for ```literalinclude```.

Comment: I added main.py :)

Comment: It contains only `import` statements. Why do you need to document that? What does Main.py actually do?

Comment: Main.py is running the main script that I need to document. I can't really show more, because it's confidential company stuff. This is a minimal example. If it works here, I can apply it to rhe rest of main.py.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is. Why do you need use `literalinclude` in the first place? Can't you document Main.py by simply describing what it does and what the arguments and options are?

Comment: Because I need to document single blocks of the whole script. I could not find an ```autodoc``` method that is capable of doing this like ```literalinclude```. I need to split it up in sub blocks, because it is 900 lines long.