# Markdown in python(replit): using hyperlinks

Tags: python

Trying to create a hyper link but I am getting an error.
My attempt:
`[Repl.it](https://repl.it)`
Error: [Repl.it](https://repl.it)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to insert hyterlink in python comment like markdown.

But how about using [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739843/how-should-i-format-a-long-url-in-a-python-comment-and-still-be-pep8-compliant)?

Leave your long URL like this

```py
# A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds [1]
# [1]: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds
```

Comment: I just ended up using the discord.embed feature thanks anyway